# xampp 1.8.1 - revert to zend 1.11

Tags: zend-framework, xampp

I've been given ownership of a project that uses Zend 1.11
I've not used Zend (let alone set it up) in a while and I'm having issues reverting the included 2.4.0 to 1.11.11

The only reference to Zend is here:
C:\xampp\php\pear\library\Zend

Is there some where else that might make my life easier?
Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run ZF1.x and ZF2.x at the same time. Just drop the current version of ZF1.12 into a location where you want it and then put it on the php include_path or just drop the library into the library for the application. ZF1 code won't try to use ZF2 components and vis a versa (They use completely different namespace types).

For example:

The current download of ZF1.12.3 minimal has this structure when extracted:

```
C:\Users
    \user 
        \Downloads
            \ZendFramework-1.12.3-minimal
                \ZendFramework-1.12.3-minimal
                     \bin /*This is where the zf.bat and zf.sh live add this path the windows path variable to use Zend_Tool CLI */
                     \library
                         \Zend /*This is where the actual code is*/
```

Take the whole `\Zend` folder and put it:

```
\project
    \application
    \library /*Put the Zend Folder here, it will be automatically included in the app*/
```

or put it where ever you want and just add that path to php.ini include_path.

This all assumes that nothing has been altered in the autoloader code for the Zend Framework application. If using the defaults doesn't work please post your `application.ini` and `bootstrap.php` as these files will usually contain the code that alters the defaults.